# Overlaying two geom_bin2d plots with two different color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I can't find how to properly specify two color scales for two different data sets passed to geom_bin2d.

The code below does not work, the first "scale_fill_gradient" call is ignored and only the last one (white to blue) is used after throwing the following error message:

> Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale.

Here a minimal code to work with:

```
require(ggplot2)
dfA <- data.frame(x=rnorm(50000, mean=5),  y=rnorm(50000, mean=5))
dfB <- data.frame(x=rnorm(30000, mean=25), y=rnorm(30000, mean=25))

ggplot() + theme_bw() + 
  geom_bin2d(data=dfA, aes(x=x, y=y), bins=100) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red") + 
  geom_bin2d(data=dfB, aes(x=x, y=y), bins=100) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="blue")
```

and this is the resulting plot:

[image]

Is there a way to specify two different color scales so that the points from dfA and those from dfB would have two different color gradients?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find out that I can solve my problem by passing the option limits=c(min, max) to scale_fill_gradient function in @Z.Lin answer.

Comment: it's not very nice to grant the correct answer tick to your own message instead of to Z.Lin. Disrespectful.

Answer (score 4):

You can create two separate plots first, then take the underlying calculated data for each plot & combine them:

```
# create separate plots
p1 <- ggplot() + theme_bw() +
  geom_bin2d(data=dfA, aes(x=x, y=y), bins=100) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red")

p2 <- ggplot() + theme_bw() +
  geom_bin2d(data=dfB, aes(x=x, y=y), bins=100) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="blue")

# combined plot using layer_data() to extract data
# from each plot above, & scale_identity to use the
# already calculated fill values
p.combined <- ggplot(data = layer_data(p1),
       aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_tile(data = layer_data(p2)) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme_bw()

# optional: add legends to the combined plot
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p.combined,
          plot_grid(get_legend(p2),
                    get_legend(p1),
                    ncol = 1),
          nrow = 1,
          rel_widths = c(1, 0.1)) # optimal relative widths may change, depending on plot dimensions
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Hi Z.Lin, thank you very much for your response. This is **almost** what I want.
Is it possible to force both scales to have the same range?

In my plot the spot corresponding to dfA data is darker than the spot from dfB because the count number is higher (I generated dfA and dfB with different size on purpose). In your solution, instead, the darkest red and the darkest blue correspond to two different counts (more than 60 counts in the red scale and more than 40 counts) while I would prefer to have two color scales but with the same min .. max range.